# How to decode AAC network audio stream using ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decode, audio-streaming, aac

I implemented a network video player (like VLC) using ffmpeg. But it can not decode AAC audio stream received from a IP camera. It can decode other audio sterams like G711, G726 etc. I set the codec ID as AV_CODEC_ID_AAC and I set channels and sample rate of AvCodecContext. But avcodec_decode_audio4 fails with an error code of INVALID_DATA. I checked previously asked questions, I tried to add extrabytes to AvCodecContext using media format specific parameters of "config=1408". And I set extradatabytes as 2 bytes of "20" and "8" but it also not worked. I appreciate any help, thanks.

```
IP CAMERA SDP:
a=rtpmap:96 mpeg4-generic/16000/1
a=fmtp:96 streamtype=5; profile-level-id=5; mode=AAC-hbr; config=1408; SizeLength=13; IndexLength=3; IndexDeltaLength=3
```

```
AVCodec* decoder = avcodec_find_decoder((::AVCodecID)id);//set as AV_CODEC_ID_AAC

AVCodecContext* decoderContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder);   

char* test = (char*)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi("1408").ToPointer();
unsigned int length;
uint8_t* extradata = parseGeneralConfigStr(test, length);//it is set as 0x14 and 0x08

decoderContext->channels = number_of_channels; //set as 1
decoderContext->sample_rate = sample_rate; //set as 16000
decoderContext->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO;
decoderContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;

decoderContext->extradata = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE + length);
memcpy(decoderContext->extradata, extradata, length);
memset(decoderContext->extradata+ length, 0, AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or at least part of the code?

Comment: I added part of code which configures AvCodecContext @ErniBrown

Comment: @eruslu, I am working on something similar, If its possible can you please share your code with me amballip@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check data for INVALID_DATA?
You can check it according to RFC

[RFC3640 (3.2  RTP Payload Structure)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3640#section-3.2)

AAC Payload can be seperated like below
`AU-Header | Size Info | ADTS | Data`

Example payload `00 10 0c 00 ff f1 60 40 30 01 7c 01 30 35 ac`

According to configs that u shared
AU-size (SizeLength=13)
AU-Index / AU-Index-delta (IndexLength=3/IndexDeltaLength=3)

The length in bits of AU-Header is `13(SizeLength) + 3(IndexLength/IndexDeltaLength) = 16`.
AU-Header `00 10`

You should use AU-size(SizeLength) value for Size Info

> AU-size: Indicates the size in octets of the associated Access Unit in the Access Unit Data Section in the same RTP packet.

First 13 (SizeLength) bits `0000000000010` equals to 2. So read 2 octets for size info.
Size Info `0c 00`

ADTS `ff f1 60 40 30 01 7c`
[ADTS Parser](https://www.p23.nl/projects/aac-header/)

ID                              MPEG-4
MPEG Layer                      0
CRC checksum absent             1
Profile                         Low Complexity profile (AAC LC)
Sampling frequency              16000
Private bit                     0
Channel configuration           1
Original/copy                   0
Home                            0
Copyright identification bit    0
Copyright identification start  0
AAC frame length                384
ADTS buffer fullness            95
No raw data blocks in frame     0

Data starts with `01 30 35 ac`.

Comment: Thank you!  When I removed first 4 bytes which includes AU header and size info. Then it works. No need to remove ADS.